# connecting to cassandra nodes on a datastax cluster on EC2 Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, datastax-enterprise, datastax, cassandra-2.0

I created a datastax cassandra Enterprise cluster with 2 cassandra nodes, 2 search nodes and 2 Analytics nodes.

Everything seems to work correctly EXCEPT, I can't connect to it from outside. If I'm on node0 server I can run the cassandra-cli and connect to the cassandra nodes on port 9160 but when I tried to connect using [datastax-rails](https://github.com/jasonmk/datastax_rails) gem, I get "No live servers" I also tried datastax devCenter which tries to connect to the native port 9042 but also didn't work. I'm really puzzled, any help is appreciated.

So after some digging I found some issues

```
   1. Port 9160 is connected and I can connect to it from telnet node0_ip 9160
   2. when I run rake ds:migrate, I get No live servers in node0_ip 
   3. I tried to connect to 'cassandra' gem instead from IRB and tried 
      a. client = Cassandra.new('example', 'node0_ip:9160')
      b. client.insert(:users, "5", {'screen_name' => "buttonscat4"})

     I got a similar error with ThriftClient::NoServersAvailable: No live servers but this time with all the IPs of all the nodes in the cluster

  4. I tried adding "client.disable_node_auto_discovery!" and I was able to connect and add stuff using 'cassandra' Gem. 

  5. I also found on https://github.com/cassandra-rb/cassandra/issues/171 that I need to  change your server to bind on a non-loopback address but have no idea what does that mean
```

The question now is how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to open up your EC2 security group to the outside on port 9160. Specifically the security group that your `node0` is using.

You can find more information about them here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html

Comment: So I open that port and I seem to connect to it from telnet but when I run rake ds:create I still get the error "No live servers in" I should also include my datastax.yml file settings                  development:
  servers: ["xx.xx.xx.xxx:9160"]
  keyspace: "my_dse_ks"
  strategy_class: "org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy"
  strategy_options: {"replication_factor": "2"}
  connection_options:
    timeout: 10
    retries: 2
    server_max_requests: 1000 
  solr:
    port: 8983
    path: /solr

Comment: Can you actually include the file in your question ?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error and got this to work by using disable_node_auto_discovery!

You can see in the documentation for this method that it says "This is primarily helpful when the cassandra cluster is communicating internally on a different ip address than what you are using to connect. A prime example of this would be when using EC2 to host a cluster. Typically, the cluster would be communicating over the local ip addresses issued by Amazon, but any clients connecting from outside EC2 would need to use the public ip."

http://rdoc.info/github/cassandra-rb/cassandra/master/Cassandra:disable_node_auto_discovery!